How do you define $\in$ set-theoretically?
It is possible to rigorously define many set operators, for example define the Cartesian product as
$$A \times B := \{(a, b) \,|\, (a\in A)\land (b \in B)\}.$$
In addition, you can define operators that output boolean values, for example $\subset$:
$$A\subset B \iff \forall x (x\in A \implies x\in B).$$
Using similar strategies, is there a non-circular, rigorous way to define $A \in B$ (which is either true or false) for two sets $A$ and $B$? Here's what I'm looking for in a definition:

A logical statement that may or may not include $:=$, as long is it has enough information to give a definite value for $A \in B$. Any other operators used (e.g $\cap, \cup, /$) must also be defined (non-circularly). If an axiom is necessary, provide the minimal axiom(s) needed to have a sound definition for $\in$.

It's also possible that there is no rigorous way to define $\in$, but I'm hoping for the alternative -- is there a way to do it?
Thanks for your consideration!
EDIT: This question has been suggested as a duplicate, but I feel my question is different because I'm asking for a way to define the properties of $\in$, not asking why there's no basic axiom defining $\in$. (Also, I believe that the fact the $\in$ is already defined by the ZFC axioms has been discussed in the comments.)

$\in$ is not defined this way. It is a symbol of the set theory (say ZFC system) language satisifes a pile of axiom. On the contrary we use $\in$ to define $\subset$.

@LidingYao So is it axiomatically defined in ZFC?

Yes, if you view $=$ a relationship symbol already defined in 1st order logic system, then the only new symbol ZFC adds is the relationship $\in$.

$\in$ is a logical primitive in ZFC and does not have a definition. The axioms of ZFC specify what properties $\in$ must satisfy.

I know that $=$ can be defined by the properties \begin{align*}x &= x,\ x=y&\iff y =x,\ (x = y) \land (y=z) &\iff x = z , \text{and}\ x = y &\implies f(x) = f(y).\ \end{align*} Is there a similar thing for $\in$? What are those properties?

The properties that axiomatically specify the behavior of $\in$ are the axioms of ZFC. But keep in mind, to say that those axioms "define"  $\in$ is a mis-use of the word "define". To "define" a mathematical symbol is different than to "axiomatize" that symbol. There is no definition of $\in$.

@LeeMosher Ok, so would it be considered rigorous to use $\in$ as part of logical statements quoting the ZFC axioms when necessary in order to explain its behavior? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

That's correct, and it is similar to any of the many axiomatic systems in mathematics.

Great, thank you so much for helping me understand!

@Mathemagician314 Your proposed definition for equality doesn't work: the total relation ($xEy$ for all $x,y$) also satisfies those properties.

For this question to make sense you need to specify the system of sets which you are working in. With ZFC there is nothing to do, as $\in$ cannot be defined there. With other set theories it is possible to interpret ZFC and hence define the $\in$ relation. See list theory for example. There are also set theories where $a:A$ (read this as: $a$ is an element of $A$) is merely a judgement, not a statement which is true or false. See SEAR for example.

As others have mentioned, $\in$ is a primitive object in $ZFC$.
However, you can construct a model of some weaker version of $ZFC$ internal to it, and here the inclusion, the belonging and the equality can be defined by a triple induction. That this is well defined (i.e: is not circular, or terminates) might not be that obvious. The definitions are as follows:

$x = y :≡ x ⊆ y ∧ y ⊆ x$
$x ⊆ y :≡ ∀uϵx.\ u∈y$
$x ∈ y :≡ ∃uϵy.\ x=u$

where $ϵ$ is a "meta-$∈$".
This is an over-simplification. The details are spicy.

Edit. Since the details were asked for, one possible implementation ---the one I know--- is with boolean models.
Define $A \rightharpoonup B$ as the set of partial functions from $A$ to $B$.
Let $\Bbb B$ be a boolean algebra closed by arbitrary joins and meets ---possibly heyting algebra is enough for this---, and define recursively
$$ V_\alpha^{\Bbb B} := \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} \left(V_\beta^{\Bbb B} \rightharpoonup \Bbb B\right) $$
for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ordinals. With this define $V^{\Bbb B}$ as the transfinite union of the $V_\alpha^{\Bbb B}$ i.e: $x \in V^{\Bbb B}$ iff $\exists\alpha:On.\ x \in V_\alpha^{\Bbb B}$. This is just a generalization of the usual cumulative hierarchy.
We will use the symbols $[\![ - ]\!]$ for interpretations inside $\Bbb B$.
Let $x,y \in V^{\Bbb B}$.
Now yes, define inside $\Bbb B$ by triple induction:
$$ [\![x = y]\!] := [\![x \subseteq y]\!] \wedge [\![y \subseteq x]\!] $$
$$ [\![x \subseteq y]\!] := \bigwedge_{z\in dom(x)} \big( x(z) \to [\![z \in y]\!] \big) $$
$$ [\![x \in y]\!] := \bigvee_{z \in dom(y)} \big( y(z) \wedge [\![x = z]\!] \big) $$

Now we can define the intensional belonging relationship $\epsilon$.
$$ [\![x \epsilon y]\!] := y(x) $$
if $x\in dom(y)$ and is equal to $\bot$ otherwise.
With this, interpreting $\bigvee$ as $\exists$ and $\bigwedge$ as $\forall$ you get the same as before the edit.

@Julian: What do you mean by "meta-$\in$"?

@Mathemagician314 Edited.
